# TypeScript type guard in class

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

I have a class whose constructor deals with async functions (HTTP reqs, actually), so I ended up doing pretty messy stuff with Promises.

```js
export { stuff }

type response = successRes | failureRes
class SomeClass {

    public result: Promise<response>;

    constructor(a, b) {
        this.result = new Promise(async resolve => resolve(await someAsyncFunc(a, b)))
    }

    isSuccess() {
        // looksLikeASuccess is a type guard
        return new Promise(async resolve => resolve(looksLikeASuccess(await this.result)))
    }

}
```

This works fine. `isSuccess()` can tell me wether the connection (`this.result`) is OK. But the thing is,  TypeScript doesn't think it's fine. If I test `isSuccess` anywhere else in my code and then use the result, it stays of type `result` and not `successResult` or `failureResult` depending on the if statement above the code. For now I use this:

```js
const result = (((await SomeClassInstance.result) as unknown) as Promise<successRes>);
```

While I'd like to use this:

```js
if (!(await SomeClassInstance.isSuccess())) return;
// Use instance's result as a 'successRes' and not as 'response'
```

How could I solve this problem / what alternatives can I use ?
I would also love to hear your thoughts about the way I use asynchronous things in the class, and eventually how I could improve this.

Comment: Async type guards are not supported. Relevant issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37681.

Comment: Side not: `new Promise` wrappers look useless https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrgYwRAzigSqqBeKBvKAEwENhiAuKYgOxCgF8BuAWAChRIoAxYgSwBs4AJwiYUOfFAhChAeyGUadJmw7QxYWdRTRc8JKgxYAPtz6CRYlqzaEICfsRFQAZnGoJgvLVBSyAthAAgiggHlzuCAAUFFS0ADRQAEaKtACUlAAKcv68OgA8Glo6AHzWdg5O0G4eXj78srIA1igAMrxNwfrIaFEiKJraEJRFQxlQ-YM6UHmwiD1GKNZsEAAemkLAUJVosAEQAMKOu3hsbFAXUGBwSfy8CBOocPzAWTl5EIWoUxBlZ6yXbbFYBCRDAeQxVIgRIpOIgNL4c6Ay7AAAWeQAdP1nltcH5AiEwggIh4YjC0kiLvR-oDiKEPDMUN1DFEEacAciLiJgMJqFAGs02h0uvMWcQAO58LZozHYl4UjlU-70IA

Comment: @AlekseyL. Good point. Not for `isSuccess` though. That's isn't my actual code, I simplified it, that's why there's some weird errors.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) so that any suggested answer can be tested against the same code you are presenting.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like to keep using `as` is the best solution. If no other answer is given by then, I'll resolve this question.